# Erlang supervisor: difference between simple_one_for_one and one_for_one restart strategies

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

What is a difference between `simple_one_for_one` and `one_for_one` restart strategies? When need to prefer one over another?

Comment: a simple way to choose them:  when the workers are same, they just use diff-arg for the same thing, use simple_one_for_one. Otherwise, use one_for_one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let *supervisor* denoted by `S`, *workers* denoted by `W`.

If `S` supervises `W1`, `W2`, `W3` under `one_for_one` restart strategy, and any of `W` dies, only that `W` is restarted.

[image: one for one]

`simple_one_for_one` restart strategy is same as `one_for_one`. Meaning if one `W` dies only that `W` is restarted. Only difference is when `S` starts, it does not have any `W`s.

`W`s are added dynamically by calling `supervisor:start_child/2`.

> When need to prefer one over another?

- `simple_one_for_one` — You need a `W` to serve something per request basis; e.g.: authentication protocols
- `one_for_one` — You need dedicated `W` processes to be there no matter what, throughout your application life cycle.